# scala.math.BigInt limitations when using bitwise operations?

Tags: scala, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators, biginteger, bit-shift

I'm trying to understand the following behaviour occuring when using bitwise and/or on a `BigInt`. The goal is to combine two `Long` values to get a "128 bit BigInt".

First, let's create two `Long` values:

```
val uuid = java.util.UUID.fromString("6fcb514b-b878-4c9d-95b7-8dc3a7ce6fd8")
val msb = BigInt(uuid.getMostSignificantBits)
// => 8055621744141552797
val lsb = BigInt(uuid.getLeastSignificantBits)
// => -7658496769846775848
```

(The `UUID` does not serve any other purpose than providing the two `Long` values that can be reproduced, so you can ignore it).

The idea is to left shift `msb` 64 bits before merging it with `lsb` using bitwise or.

```
val result = (msb << 64) | lsb
```

However, the result equals `lsb` itself. In other words, `((msb << 64) | lsb) == lsb` is `true`. Apart from that, `((msb << 64) & lsb) == (msb << 64)` is also `true`.

Why is that?

edit:

The bit shift seems to work, the intermediary result of `msb << 64` has 127 binary digits (probably a leading zero).

Comment: The sign bit of the negative value is being carried forward.  All those leading bits obliterate the shifted value when OR'd together.  It should work with 2 positive `Long` values.

Comment: Of course, thanks. For some reason I though the leading 1's of the negative number would not exceed 64bits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one approach that might get you what you're after.

```
import java.nio.ByteBuffer

val uuid = java.util.UUID.fromString("6fcb514b-b878-4c9d-95b7-8dc3a7ce6fd8")

val bb = ByteBuffer.allocate(16)
bb.putLong(uuid.getMostSignificantBits)
bb.putLong(uuid.getLeastSignificantBits)

val result: BigInt = bb.array.foldLeft(BigInt(0))((bi,b) => (bi << 8)|(0xFF & b))
// result = 148599992668788990968304946804723445720

// proof it works
println(f"$result%x")  // 6fcb514bb8784c9d95b78dc3a7ce6fd8
```

Comment: Thanks, that works. But since we need the `ByteBuffer` and `Array[Byte]` anyway, it's also possible to just do `BigInt(bb.array)`